# Boost::Program_options, passing an unknown command line argument

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am using boost::program_options to pass configuration files for my program. In particular I use often command line overriding of some of the options. For example if I register two options "opt1" and "opt2" I can successfully override the default values by running my program with

```
 myProgram.exe --opt1=option_value_1 --opt2=option_value_2
```

All good, but it happened already few times that I run my program mistakenly as

```
 myProgram.exe --opt1=option_value_1 opt2=option_value_2
```

In such a case (missing double hyphen) no error is thrown. In fact I can apparently run myProgram as

```
 myProgram.exe list of any unregistered and unknown values
```

and it still runs correctly. I would expect to at least get informed that something unexpected happened. Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: Validate the unknown option values (they should appear in the list of input files or whatever you take from unknown arguments, e.g. check if these files exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `allow_unregistered()` from your parse command. You command should simply be

```
po::store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
```

then exception will be thrown on unknown options.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#idp123440592

If you want exception/error, if option has no "--" you should write extra parser, something like this, can help you

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> fix_option(const std::string& value)
{
   std::string name = value;
   std::string val;
   std::string::size_type pos = name.find("=");
   if (pos != std::string::npos)
   {
      val = name.substr(pos + 1);
      name = name.substr(0, pos);
   }
   if (name.substr(0, 2) != "--")
   {
      throw std::logic_error(std::string("invalid command, no -- in command: ") + name);
   }
   return std::make_pair(name.substr(2), val);
}
```

[code example](http://ideone.com/4q24cL)

results:

```
./new --help=j

output: j

./new help=j

output: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  invalid command, no -- in command: help
```

Comment: Thanks, one would expect that there is some internal check already provided by boost. This approach will not work if you want to simultaneously support one-hyphen notation. In any case, this works well for my particular needs.

Comment: @pegazik _'This approach will not work if you want to simultaneously support one-hyphen notation.'_ Why?? How did you implement it? Usually one-hyphen notation is realized with an additional single character shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [*boost::program_options*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options.html) does not recognize positional arguments per default. This means that non-option arguments like `opt2=option_value_2` are ignored. However, the documentation is not clear about it. You can enable handling of positional arguments with `basic_command_line_parser::positional()`.

## By Example

```
try {
    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).
                options(desc).positional({}).run(),
              vm);
    po::notify(vm);
} catch (po::too_many_positional_options_error &e) {
    // A positional argument like `opt2=option_value_2` was given
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
} catch (po::error_with_option_name &e) {
    // Another usage error occurred
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

## Explanation

Basically,

```
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
```

has been replaced with

```
po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
            .options(desc).positional({}).run(),
          vm);
```

As I understand the documentation, `parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc)` is a shorthand for `command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).run()`. Through adding a call to [`positional()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/basic_command_line_parser.html), we are enabling handling of positional arguments. Through specifying `{}`, no positional arguments are allowed. An instance of [`too_many_positional_options_error`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/too_many_posi_idp135754368.html) is thrown when too many positional arguments are given.